# Cannot refer to an instance field page while explicitly invoking a constructor

Tags: java, webautomation

[This is my BaseForm class which I would like to use it to validate if my page(Main_Page) is open or not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mv4pQ.png)

[This is my Main_Page class which inherits from BaseForm class, and I'm trying invoke the constructor and the error is shown in my screenshot, I need to do the following operation(see screenshot) in order to use the isPageOpen() to validate my page is open or not, but this error is keeping me away from doing such is there any one who could tell me the right way to do this?? **also I'm not allowed to use static methods**.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOhBB.png)

Comment: Make the field static.

Comment: The value for `page` field will be assigned *after* `super` call in constructor. Before that it will hold `null`, which is its *initial* value, so something you don't want to use (otherwise you would explicitly write `null` instead of `page`). Error is trying to prevent you from making that mistake.

Comment: Please don't post images of code or text.  And please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: okay now right after I make the field as static The constructor BaseForm(WebElement) is undefined error occurs...

Comment: Please read the [ask] link and then giving your question and [edit] so that it meets or exceeds site standards including showing all code and error messages as text, not as images.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I need to do the following operation(see screenshot) in order to use the isPageOpen() to validate my page is open or not, but this error is keeping me away from doing such is there any one who could tell me the right way to do this?? ..."*

Essentially, the *super* class must be instantiated prior to your sub-class, *Main_Page*.

As a remedy, you could create a method within your *super* class to set the value.
Additionally, provide a *default constructor*, so you won't have to assign a value.

For example.

```java
class BaseForm {
    String string;

    BaseForm() {
    }
    
    BaseForm(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }

    void setString(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }
}

class Main_Page extends BaseForm {
    String string = "";

    Main_Page(String string) {
        super();
        super.setString(this.string);
    }
}
```

Comment: Now the original poster has no motivation to improve their post.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, you can't understand what they are asking?  You're being serious?

Comment: You misunderstand me. I can understand, but as written, what good is the question for future visitors? That is the whole reason for this site's existence: to be a library of high-quality Q&A's for future visitors with similar problems. Sure you can provide an answer that helps the OP, but without a complete and well-written question, that is all that you can do. And quite frankly, the question is currently very low-quality.